# why am i getting this "E/org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of: onErrorResponse:" error?

Tags: java, android, json, jsonexception

I am sending a post request to the server using volley library from android device to the spring backend. This post request is for registering the new user. Every thing works fine as intended the post request is sent to server the server accepts the request and new user is created on the database. but instead of getting user created sucessfully toast i get error creating user in my android app.

I can't find what is worng with the code.

this is my code on android:

```
// sends data to the server
public void createNewUser(){

    final String BASE_URL = BaseUrl.BASE_URL_CUSTOMER;
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    // sending the json file to the server
    JSONObject postParams = new JSONObject();
    try {
        postParams.put("firstName", customer.getFirstName());
        postParams.put("lastName",customer.getLastName());
        postParams.put("email",customer.getEmail());
        postParams.put("password",customer.getPassword());
        Log.e("testing", "createNewUser: "+postParams.toString());
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(e.getMessage(), "createNewUser: error while creating a new user");
    }

   JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL, postParams, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
           Log.e(response.toString(), "onResponse: " );
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Creating new user",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error:Creating new user",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           Log.e(error.getMessage(), "onErrorResponse:");
       }


   });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

i check on post man and my response looks like this:

```
{
"firstName": "xyz",
"lastName": "abc",
"email": "xyzabc@gmail.com",
"password": "12345678",
"_links": {
"self": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/customers/22"
},
"customer": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/customers/22"
}
}
}
```

this is my full error:

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:73)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)
 Caused by: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:68)
```

Comment: Your backend is probably returning the wrong response code, try it with postman/insomnia and see the response from server

Comment: i checked on the postman and response seems fine

Comment: Is the response a properly formatted json? both in case of success and error?

Comment: @ZohaibAmir i've added the response.. you can check

Comment: Check error in debug mode and see what message/content it has

Comment: I have posted the error on my question title

Comment: Does it have any raw response string/message from server?

Comment: I've added that too

Comment: for some reason, your server sends an empty string in response, this could be because you are using wrong request (GET/POST), something is different from the request you sent in postman, make sure everything matches exactly, like parameters etc